# R Find tags in text automatically

Tags: r, tags

I´m not really into text mining, so I ask my question here. 
I have some texts and I would like to analyse which topics(tags) the texts are about.
So I asked myself what´s the best way to do so.

First of all, I prepared the texts and removed stopwords with the tm package:

```
library(tm)

sample2 = c('This text is about the wheather. Today the wheater is really bad.', 'The dog is barking very loud. That is annoying.')
myStopwords <- c(stopwords("english"), "today")

df <- do.call("rbind", lapply(sample2, as.data.frame))
colnames(df) = "texts"
corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(df$texts))
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, content_transformer(tolower))
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removePunctuation)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeNumbers)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, function(x) removeWords(x, myStopwords))
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, stemDocument, language = c("english"))
```

Now I created a TermDocumentMatrix

```
td.mat <- TermDocumentMatrix(corpus, control=list(minWordLength = 1))
```

and now I would like to find frequent nouns (no verbs or adjectives). Text 1 should have "text" and "wheater" as tags and Text 2 should have "dog".
Can anybody tell me how to do that?

Comment: your question is about finding noun/verb/adjectif, you should be more specific. This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4610974/extracting-adjnounadjnounnoun-prepadjnounnoun-from-text-jus

Comment: Yes, I do not want to get something like "bad" or "annoying" as a tag, because that's not what the text is about...