# How to extract adjectives and adverbs from vector of text in R

Tags: r, extract

I want to extract adjectives and adverbs from a vector, is there any way to do this ?

```
input <- "It's a good phone"
```

Expected output : `"good"`

Comment: Please provide an example of what you have tried.

Comment: Wide open question here, but I'd recommend looking at NLP projects in R like [this one](https://rpubs.com/lmullen/nlp-chapter) or [this one](https://github.com/quanteda/spacyr) or other SO questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600612/extracting-nounnoun-or-adjnounnoun-from-text)

Comment: I see no reason at all to close this question. @cody-gray can you elaborate ? The question is precise enough and has sample data and an expected output.`r` is often used for text mining and I don't see how a question on parts of speech is out of scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use *tidytext* :

```
library(tidytext)
library(tidyverse)
unnest_tokens(tibble(txt="It's a good phone"),word, txt) %>%
  left_join(parts_of_speech) %>%
  filter(pos %in% c("Adjective","Adverb")) %>%
  pull(word) %>%
  unique
# [1] "good"
```

Comment: Error in Ribble(text="it's a good phone",word,text) could not find function Ribble ,it's after package installed

Comment: yeah but i didn't write that :)

Comment: Sorry tibble*,but now could not find function "%>%"

Comment: I edited to attach *tidyverse*, please see how it goes now

Comment: Could not find function unnest_tokens :'(

Comment: make sure to run `library(tidytext)` first, and if you didn't install the package before, do it with `install.packages("tidytext")`

Comment: It's worked,thank you.